# Apache directory access with virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, virtualhost

I have a virtual host with a configuration like that.

When i'm trying to get into foobar.com/dir providing valid username/password pair i get 403 forbidden page instead of that directory contents.

www.foobar.com/dir has 777 rights, .httpaswd is chmoded 644. But i can't figure out why i am still not seeing contents. Please, give me a hint.

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost 
ServerName www.foobar.com
ServerAlias www.foobar.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/foobar
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All       
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/foobar>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/foobar/dir>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        AuthName "Authorize yourself, please!"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
        AuthGroupFile /dev/null
        Allow from All
        Order Allow,Deny
            Options +Indexes<<- that one should be added                              
        Require valid-user
```

Comment: What apache says in access/error logs?

Comment: Shouldn't you have `Options +Indexes` in there somewhere?

Comment: Error log says" [Sun Jun 24 01:12:45 2012] [error] [client <ipadress>] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/foobar/dir/

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Options +Indexes` in the last `<Directory>` statement